# Evitar que se cierre una ventana modal al abrir otra

Tags: javascript, html

**Tengo los siguientes modales:**

**> primero abro este:**

```
<div id="my-id" class="uk-flex-top" uk-modal>
<i class="material-icons uk-text-success md-icon uk-form-file" id="btnCompr" href="#modal-full" uk-toggle>search </i>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-margin-auto-vertical"></div>
</div>
```

> Pero quiero que al dar click al boton se abra segundo sin cerrar el
>   primero

```
<div id="<i class="material-icons uk-text-success md-icon uk-form-file" id="btnCompr" href="#modal-full" uk-toggle>search </i>" class="uk-modal-full" uk-modal>


 <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <button class="uk-modal-close-full uk-close-large" type="button" uk-close></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comportamiento por defecto del `dialog` de UIKit es cerrar cuando se abre otro. En esta respuesta de SO explican cómo evitarlo. Básicamente hay que añadir al botón la propiedad `data-uk-modal="{target:'#modal1', modal: false}` o hacerlo por javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Obtenemos la modal
    var modal2 = UIkit.modal("#modal2", {modal: false});
    //En el evento click del botón del modal1 abrimos el modal2
    $("#btn2").on("click",function(){
    modal2.show();
   });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/14b7oom8/) de ejemplo con atributos

[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/k0dwt311/) con javascript

Comment: al agregar la propiedad : `data-uk-modal="{target:'#modal1', modal: false}` y lo intenté hacer por javascript pero me da el siguiente error:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: UIkit is not defined`

Comment: Eso es porque no estás cargando el script de UIkit

Comment: tengo en mi index.php  `<script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/uikit.js"></script>` **es correcto no?**

Comment: Sí tienes una carpeta llamada "js" y dentro los scripts sí. De todas formas te sobra uno (el .min.js es el mismo que el otro pero minificado para que ocupe menos)

Comment: creo que es un fallo de la version 3(BETA) estaba viendo que hacian algo como `Import UIkit from 'uikit'` pero no funciona

Comment: No es un bug. La solución que te di JavaScript es para utilizar con el módulo (webpack). Con el atributo debería funcionarte. ¿Tienes el CSS cargado?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.css">` efectivamente, la vrd no me explico el porque del fallo si los modales si se muestran correctamente

Comment: Quita la parte JavaScript, no te hace falta. Y si puedes poner un fiddle con tu código

Comment: pues igual no funciona de las dos maneras

Comment: Debería, luego hago una prueba

Comment: He modificado un poco el código Javascript para que funcione, aunque lo más limpio me parece utilizar el atributo uk-modal